# Incorrect results while using multiple conditions in where clause in SQL

Tags: sql, join

I have the below query where I need to filter data based on multiple where conditions, but in the result set I get incorrect results not satisfying the conditions. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT TOP 1 a.ID FROM Counselor a
            inner join levelMapping b on  a.UserLevel=b.LevelMapped
            inner join mUser c on a.ID=c.ID
            WHERE               

            a.HomeLocation=@RES_location  and a.PrimarySkill=@RES_PrimarySkill and
            b.LEVELINDEX<= 
            --8
            (case when @RES_levelIndex in (8,9) then @RES_levelIndex-1 else @RES_levelIndex-2 end)     
            and MappedCC_Count<=10 and a.CUrrLoc not like '%Out Of India%' and a.CUrrLoc not like '%Client%'
            and c.AG='XYZ'

            order by b.levelindex desc,
            --case when @RES_levelIndex=9 then b.levelindex end asc,
            --case when @RES_levelIndex > 9 then b.levelindex end desc,
                  a.MappedCC_Count asc
```

Example:
The result below shows Conselor(CC) with different location and skill has been mapped to user although our logic does not allow this:

[image]

Comment: With out looking at table data and input data(variables) it is impossible to fix your query

Comment: Could you show more information? not sure what you want

Comment: I am trying to select a user based on multiple conditions like similar Location and skill etc. This logic runs within a loop for multiple cases. But in the final result, we get few users where only partial conditions are met. e.g it chooses a user with similar location but different skill although both conditions are joined by an "AND"

Comment: `NULL` values could be an issue in this case.

Comment: I tried handling null, still am getting results which do not satisfy all conditions. :(

Comment: please add the sample data and expected output

Comment: I have added sample result in the question above. Please have a look.